# Docker container mac address change

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, networking, centos

I have an application that uses a MAC Address for licensing. I'd like to run this application in a docker container for CI/CD purposes. I created a docker container and use the `ENTRYPOINT` to run a shell script. The issue I am running into now is that when I try to ping any server I get network errors. I am wondering if this is something that I can fix or if I am doing this incorrectly. I'd love to find a solution for this so I can test scripts that I write for this system before pushing them to production. I'll be around to answer any additional questions.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM centos:latest
COPY startup.sh /startup.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/startup.sh"]
```

**startup.sh**

```
ip link set dev eth0 down;
ip link set dev eth0 address 02:42:ac:11:00:11;
ip link set dev eth0 up;
```

**Errors**

```
sh-4.4# ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
29: eth0@if30: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:11 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0

sh-4.4# ping google.com
ping: google.com: Name or service not known

sh-4.4# ping 4.4.4.4
connect: Network is unreachable
```

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/38406550/11715259

Answer (score 1):

If you need to override low-level networking details like this, you should generally do it at the Docker level.  For example, there is a [`docker run --mac-address` option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings) that you can specify when you launch the container.  You shouldn't need to run `ip`, `ifconfig`, or similar network-management commands in your container's startup sequence; this is entirely handled by Docker.

```sh
docker run --mac-address 02:42:ac:11:00:11 ...
```

Comment: My issue with this method is that in GitLab's CI/CD I do not think I have control over how an image is run. I would need an image to be built with this MAC address so that I don't need to run it with any extra arguments.

Comment: @David Maze, is it possible to `start` the container with a specific mac-address? I realized that if you `run` the container with a specific mac-address as you suggest, and then you `stop` it and `start` it again, the mac-address will once again be assigned automatically (overriding the one you first ran it with)

Comment: I never ever use `docker start`.  `docker rm` the stopped container and `run` it again.  I wouldn't expect the address to change in this case, but it also seems odd, potentially a Docker bug.  (`docker start`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/) takes almost no options and in the unusual event you do need it you can't change most of the container options with it.